# Common expressions of surprise in American and British English

Tags: slang, expressions

I'm trying to learn English and I would like to know what are the expressions of surprise with positive meaning (slang or not, but not vulgar) currently used in spoken English for USA and Britain.

Is "whoa" correct? Or is "wow"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [wow](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wow) and [whoa](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whoa) are used in American and British English as expressions of surprise.

If you look at the context in which the words appear, for example, [in the Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=12007001), one distinction between the words is that *whoa* is also used with the meaning "slow down, wait" (from its meaning as a command to a horse), whereas *wow* seems to be generally only used for surprise. This is even more apparent in the results in the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/?c=bnc&q=12007027). There, also, some of the results for *wow* are actually for *wowee*, a version I would have considered colloquial or outdated-sounding if hearing in AmE (but note that the BNC data also stops at the 1990s).

One [discussion of *wow* and *whoa*](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2011/02/whoa.html) mentions:

> The OED gives spellings and definitions that seem exactly right.
>
> > ***whoa* wəʊ** ‘a word of command to a horse or other draught-animal to stop or stand still’ (from 1843)
> > ***wow* waʊ** ‘now chiefly expressing astonishment or admiration’ (from 1892)
>
> On the other hand the on-line Urban Dictionary offers further, alternative, definitions of whoa that make it a partial synonym of wow:
>
> > 1. To express surprise (interj)
> > 2. To express astonishment (interj)

In the comments on that discussion, a number of speakers of different dialects offer insights. One BrE speaker mentions about spelling:

> I think there's a third interjection, pronounced the same as whoa, but maybe spelled woah or woh. That's what's being said in the cartoon, and it combines the two meanings - an expression of surprise and a request to stop.

[A blog about AmE and BrE further discusses the *woah* spelling](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2009/04/whoa-and-woah.html):

> The OED lists *woah* as a variant of *woa* which is a variant of *whoa*... I don't remember ever seeing the *woah* spelling (I'd want to pronounce it as two syllables: wo-ah, like Noah) before moving to England [as an American], but it's a very popular spelling here. Searching just UK sites, one gets ~170,000 hits for *woah* and ~255,000 for *whoa*.

Comment: As you say, *Whoa!* is primarily used to mean *Hold on, there!*, or *Slow down!*. In the UK, the 'surprise' version is usually transcribed as *Phwoar!* (often with sexual/titillating overtones), or *Phew!* (often with overtones of relief that the surprise didn't end in disaster).

Comment: Phwoar! That's a new one for me.

Comment: I did actually find [phwoah](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/phwoah) in OALD but I didn't include it as I didn't want to give the mistaken impression that this exists in AmE. Its existence was a surprise to me ;) We have *phew!* but I suppose I'd say something entirely different for *phwoar!*, perhaps *rawr!* or *ooh!*, if it was ever written.